# Omitting header in textfile

Tags: python, python-2.7

I got a text file that receives a new line each time I run the script. It receives a new line when everything was OK (in the try block), and a new line when something was wrong (from the except block). Everything works fine as in terms of adding new lines. But I also got 1 header, that is added the first time the text file is created/written. So every time I run the script, it adds not only one of those new lines, but ofc again the header. I can comment out the line where I add the header and just remove the loop, but how does this propperly works? I can't figure out how it works with a for loop (I think I might need one of those..sorry pretty new to python).

So what I tried:

```
log = 'log.txt'
logfile = file(log, "a") # 'a' for appending the existing file
```

Then I got my big header full of information (formatting exactly like that):

```
header ='''
############################################################
#                                                          #
#                                                          #
#  Log file for bla station                                #
#                                                          #
#              xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                   #
#               xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx                    #
#                                                          #
#           Contact: bla@bla.at                            #
#                                                          #
############################################################\n\n'''
```

then further in the except block (for instance):

```
error = "ERROR! No file found!"

for head in open(logfile, 'r'):
    if head == header:
        continue
    logfile.write(header)
    logfile.write(timestamp + error + '\n')
```

But I got the following error message:

```
    for head in open(logfile, "r"):

    TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, file found
```

What does that mean and what do I miss? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your immediate problem is this line:

```
for head in open(logfile, 'r'):
```

The [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) function wants a filename, but you're giving it an open `file` object, as defined here:

```
logfile = file(log, "a") # 'a' for appending the existing file
```

That's what the `TypeError` is telling you. It's trying to use the `file` object as a string or buffer specifying the filename, and a `file` object doesn't know how to do that.

What you want is `open(log, 'r')`.

As a side note, you really should be using `with` statements (or otherwise closing the files), *especially* when writing.

---

But there's another problem here. Your `header` is multiple lines long, but each `head` is a single line, so there's no way `head == header` could ever possibly be true.

---

More importantly, the logic here doesn't seem to make sense. What your code is *trying* to do is: For every existing line in the file except the header, append a new header and a new log message. So, if your file looked like this:

```
HEADER
message 1
message 2
message 3
```

You're going to end up with:

```
HEADER
message 1
message 2
message 3
HEADER
new message
HEADER
new message
HEADER
new message
```

And that can't be what you want. I think you're just trying to write a header iff it doesn't have one, and then write the new log line either way, right? So, your logic has to actually say that.

One really simple solution is to assume that any non-empty file has a header. You could do that with, e.g.:

```
with open(log, 'r+') as logfile:
    logfile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
    if not logfile.tell():
        # The end is still position 0, so we have to write a header
        logfile.write(header)
    logfile.write(timestamp + error + '\n')
```

---

Finally, you should really consider looking at the [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module. It's pretty big and complicated, but notice that the docs start with three tutorials that will probably get you what you want. You can pretty easily write a handler subclass that writes the header only when it creates a new file. And one advantage of this is that you can later extend it to, e.g., use rotating log files, and your existing logic will keep working (you just need to mix in a different base handler). Or you can change log formats just by specifying a different formatter, instead of having to find every place you explicitly used `timestamp + msg` and fix them all. And so on.

Comment: My hero! It works :-) Though file.seek(offset[, whence]) requires os.SEEK_END (not is.SEEK_END...just a small typo) :-) Thx a lot!

Comment: @GeoEki: Thanks for catching the typo. (I originally wrote it with `2`, then after copying and pasting it into my answer I thought it would be clearer with the name and edited it in… a nice illustration of why you should edit code in your code, not in your posts. :)